# Development environment clean installation

Tags: windows, ubuntu, development, computing-environment

I'm about to install a new and clean development environment. To accomplish that, I would like a Windows operating system (possibly Windows 7) and a Ubuntu one (possibly the most recent, 10.04). To allow sharing data between the two operating systems, I'm thinking to create a partition (workspace, for example) with using NTFS to format it and that be automatically mounted by Ubuntu.

In terms of the partitioning schema, how would be better to organize the previous mentioned partitions?

Comment: Note: with older versions of windows, you need to install windows first.  I've never done a Win7/Linux duel boot system, so I don't know if this is still the case (but it won't hurt to do windows first)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partitions:

```
  (linux swap partition)
/ (root for linux)
/mnt/workspace  (shared partition for workspace)
/mnt/windows  (where windows is installed)
```

From windows, you'll see:

```
C:\  (windows instalation partition)
D:\  (workspace: drive letter might vary)
```

Depending on how you set it up, you may or may not be able to access your linux root partition.  But if all that has is linux program files, this won't matter.

Note:  it is worth considering making `/home/` a separate partition as well, so it can be accessed from windows.

Comment: And the recommended order for the partitions is the one that you mentioned on your post? In terms of installation, what is the recommended order? I do know that a post installation of Windows makes invalid the grub boot manager.

Thanks in advance,
Best regards!

Comment: Hi again!

For Windows, does anyone know the recommend size for the system partition?

Best regards!

Comment: I don't know anything about what order to put them in.

Comment: I don't know the min recommended size for Win7.  But I usually do 10% (of the drive) for each OS and the rest for the shared partition.  If you're worried about space, make the OS and workspace paritions smaller and leave empty (unused) space between them.  That way you can increase their size later.